# Using For Loop to create a List to then export with Pandas to Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

Good Morning,

I've been working on this for about 3 days now.  I need some help.

I'm using BeautifulSoup to allow me to parse it.  Everything I'm doing works all the way down to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[Var1]})
df.append([Var1], ignore_index=False)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Names', index=False, header=True, startrow=start_row)
```

I'm grabbing a total of X variables and stripping them. It could be 3, it could be 100. What I would like to do is grab them and write them to an excel sheet formatted so:

Name

Var1

Var1

Var1

Var1

The problem I'm running into is that it only writes the last entry, even though I can use:

```
print(df)
```

and see 10 entries.

Which is why I think maybe a list would make it easier.  If I could figure out how to iterate through the for loop and create a list where list=[Var1, Var1, Var1...]I could then just throw that list into the:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[Var1]})
```

Although looking at it now it might not work.

```
import requests  
import sys
import re  
import pandas as pd  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

page = requests.get('https://thisisanexampleurl.com')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

start_row = 0

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('my_excel_sheet.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

for link in soup.find_all('h3'):

    Var1 = link.get_text() #grabbing a header string with a Name in it
    Var1 = Var1.strip() #stripping out leading/ending spaces because there's a ton


    df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[Var1]})
    df.append([Var1], ignore_index=False)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Names', index=False, header=True, startrow=start_row)
```

I'm terrible at this I realize, but I appreciate any and all help.

Thank you so much.

Comment: For each link you are defining the dataframe again and appending values. Thats y it just shows the last appended value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put each `Var1` that you get in each iteration of the `for link in soup...` loop inside a structure (like a list) and *only after the loop is done* you transform that list into a DataFrame and write it to Excel. Otherwise, each call to `df.to_excel` simply overwrites the same excel file over and over, and you only see the last file that has been written.

For example:

```
vars_list = []
for link in soup.find_all('h3'):
    Var1 = link.get_text() #grabbing a header string with a Name in it
    Var1 = Var1.strip() #stripping out leading/ending spaces because there's a ton
    vars_list.append(Var1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': vars_list})
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Names', index=False, header=True, startrow=start_row)
```

Also, writing `df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[Var1]})` simply creates a dataframe with a single column `Name` and a single row containing `Var1`. Even though you *could* initialize a DataFrame and append to it with each iteration, the fact that you write `df = pd.DataFrame...` inside your for loop effectively means that your DataFrame is overwritten in each iteration.

Comment: You are wonderful. Thank you for the explanation.  I knew I was doing something that was basically overwriting it while it was looping, but I couldn't figure it out.